# Cannot lose focus when click outside input

Tags: javascript, html

So the problem is every time I click outside the input focus keeps on 
i tried several codes but they didn't work for me

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").focus(function(){
    const background = true;
    if(background == true){
      $('form').css({
       'background-color': '#fff',
       'transition': 'background-color 1s ease-out'
    });
    } 
    else {
      $('input').blur(function(){
        if(background == false){
          $('form').css({
            'background-color': 'transparent'
          });
        }
    })
  }
})});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input" placeholder="How may we help you?">
    <div class="input-append">
      <button type="button" class="btn"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: hi, can you elaborate? what you wanna do actually? You wanna do something on blur, right?

Comment: so, you don't want the input to lose focus or you do? clicking outside the input definitely loses focus on that input

Comment: by the way `const background = "none";
            if(background == 'none'){` is equivalent to `if (true) {` ... since background is always none

Comment: i want to lose focus when click outside the input

Comment: That's how inputs behave normally - they lose focus when you click outside of them - perhaps it's the logic in your code that is the problem - especially since you never add a blur handler since background is ALWAYS `"none"` therefore your `else` code never runs

Comment: Can you edit your post to add some periods, commas, and extra words? "every time I click outside the input focus keep on i tried" is not something most people will be able to understand.

Comment: @JaromandaX is right, it's default behaviour to lose focus when you click outside

Comment: the thing is the input not losing focus when clicking outside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("input").focus(function(){
       $('form').css({
          'background-color': '#fff',
          'transition': 'background-color 1s ease-out'
           });
    });

    $('input').blur(function(){
        $('form').css({
           'background-color': 'transparent'
            });
    });
});
```

Try this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you wanna do something like this

1. On Focus- Change color of form background to #fff(White)
2. On unfocus - Change form background to transparent

```
$('input').focus(function () {
    $('form').css({
        'background-color': '#fff',
        'transition': 'background-color 1s ease-out'
    });
});

$('input').blur(function () {
    $('form').css({
        'background-color': 'transparent'
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried before the first code you wrote but it didn't work for me so I thought the if statement will work

Comment: You know the actual problem in your code. You are trying to add event listener (Blur) inside another event (Focus). These 2 events are separate.